# How to select multiple element in nodejs and d3

Tags: node.js, d3.js, data-visualization

I have 2 elements of the same class in a HTML document created using d3

```
var bar1 = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "bar");

var bar2 = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "bar");
```

A nodejs server is sending data which i am listening to

I want both these elements to reflect that data but only the first one is actually showing up the data

```
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
  var box = d3.selectAll(".bar").data(data).style("background-color", function(d) {return d});
});
```

I even tried

```
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
  var box = d3.selectAll(".bar").data(data);

  box.each(function(){

    d3.select(this).style("background-color", function(d) {return d});
  })

});
```

But even this didn't work out. How do I reflect the changes on both the divs.

Comment: data is colour names being emitted randomly by a nodejs server script.

Comment: And what does it look like? Is it an array, an object..?

Comment: Well if it's a single element, `.data()` will only ever match a single element. Hence the update selection (which you're working with) has only one element.

Comment: Is it possible to alternate between these selections? That is to say, once the first element is updated then the next. It would be even better if these elements could be chosen randomly.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If `data` is just the name of a colour you want everything to have, then `d3.selectAll(".bar").style("background-color", data)` should work fine.